# apache-camel messaging bridge (mirroring)

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use the "messaging bridge" functionality of apache camel.
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/messaging-bridge.html

As far as i see, the message on the original messaging system will not remain.
Can i make a copy of the message instead of forwarding it so that it is mirrored between the messaging systems?

This is my simple setup:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


 <bean id="5xConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
      <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
      <property name="password" value="admin"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="5xConnectionFactory"/>
      <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
   </bean>


 <bean id="7xConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61617"/>
      <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
      <property name="password" value="admin"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="jmsConfig2" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="7xConnectionFactory"/>
      <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="artemis" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig2"/>
   </bean>


   <camelContext id="bridgeContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
      <route id="bridge_TEST.FOO">
         <from uri="activemq:queue:TEST.FOO"/>
         <wireTap uri="direct:tap"/>
         <to uri="artemis:queue:TEST.FOO"/>
      </route>
   </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Do you really want to leave the original message on the source queue?  Could you just have two <to/> clauses?